# MYSQL UNION AND WHERE CONDITION

Tags: mysql, union, where-clause

I am unable to put a WHERE condition for a UNION in MYSQL.
Now with the below SQL line I am getting all the records in the tables and not filtering date between 2 dates.

My order by is working fine. I want to do this without creating a view

```
    SELECT *
    FROM DCHDR AS H
    LEFT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON H.DC_No = T.DC_Nos
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM DCHDR AS H
    RIGHT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON H.DC_No = T.DC_Nos
    WHERE H.DC_date
    BETWEEN '2013-03-02'
    AND '2013-03-11'
    ORDER BY `Product_Desc` ASC
    LIMIT 510 , 30
```

Comment: having a condition on a potentially NULL field in a RIGHT JOIN makes it equal to an INNER JOIN

Answer (score 6):

Unlike `ORDER BY`, `WHERE` clauses in a union affect only that part of the union (the single `SELECT` query it is attached to), and *not* the entire union.

Either put your union in a subquery and filter on the results:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM DCHDR AS H
    LEFT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON H.DC_No = T.DC_Nos
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM DCHDR AS H
    RIGHT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON H.DC_No = T.DC_Nos
) H
WHERE H.DC_date BETWEEN '2013-03-02' AND '2013-03-11'
ORDER BY `Product_Desc` ASC
LIMIT 510, 30
```

Or duplicate your condition for each part:

```
SELECT *
FROM DCHDR AS H
LEFT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON H.DC_No = T.DC_Nos
WHERE H.DC_date BETWEEN '2013-03-02' AND '2013-03-11'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM DCHDR AS H
RIGHT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON H.DC_No = T.DC_Nos
WHERE H.DC_date BETWEEN '2013-03-02' AND '2013-03-11'
ORDER BY `Product_Desc` ASC
LIMIT 510 , 30
```

---

**It looks though that you are trying to simulate a full join.** Might I suggest the following query instead, which should be *much* faster (and actually do what you want, which is *not* filtering the second part of the union):

```
SELECT *
FROM DCHDR AS H
LEFT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON H.DC_No = T.DC_Nos
WHERE H.DC_date BETWEEN '2013-03-02' AND '2013-03-11'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM DCHDR AS H
RIGHT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON H.DC_No = T.DC_Nos
WHERE H.DC_No IS NULL
ORDER BY `Product_Desc` ASC
LIMIT 510 , 30
```

Note if you have duplicate rows in `DCDTL` that you are purposely trying to filter out with `UNION`, you can change the `UNION ALL` to `UNION`, but I suspect this is actually *not* the case.

Comment: The above line gives an error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias. So i tried changing Product_Desc fieldname to T.Product_Desc, Even then no use, same error.

Comment: Yeah I added the `H` alias a bit late. Sorry. (Note the `H` after the closing parenthesis).

Comment: I tried both the sql lines you have given, and also with UNION ALL and only UNION, all give ZERO records result.

Comment: Yes this is a full join. second table DCDTL has duplicate records. NONE of the above gives any result.

Comment: I have checked the data, surely there are records, I can give see them without doing UNION

Comment: Are you sure there are at least 510 records there?

Comment: There are 526 records in DCDTL and 215 in DCHDR

Comment: Yes you are right, after removing the *, IT IS WORKING, pl check if this is correct. SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT DC_No, DC_date, T.DC_Nos, T.Qty, T.Product_Desc
FROM DCHDR AS H
LEFT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON DC_No = T.DC_Nos
UNION
SELECT DC_No, DC_date, T.DC_Nos, T.Qty, T.Product_Desc
FROM DCHDR AS H
RIGHT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON DC_No = T.DC_Nos
) AS sub
WHERE DC_date
BETWEEN '2013-03-02'
AND '2013-03-11'
ORDER BY Product_Desc ASC

Comment: @sridhars Yes except as newtover correctly explains in a comment, you may as well just remove the right side of the join anyway since you're filtering on a potentially nullable column.

Answer (score 4):

Try to put that inside a subquery and do the filtering in the outer one:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM DCHDR AS H
    LEFT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON H.DC_No = T.DC_Nos
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM DCHDR AS H
    RIGHT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON H.DC_No = T.DC_Nos
) AS sub
WHERE DC_date BETWEEN '2013-03-02'
                  AND '2013-03-11'
ORDER BY `Product_Desc` ASC;
LIMIT 510 , 30
```

Comment: @Mohmoud Gagaml  The line you have given is giving an error saying: #1060 - Duplicate column name 'Area', I have this column in both the tables, is it because of this ?

Comment: @Mohmoud Gagaml  Now i cannot rename any column as I have many php dependent on these.

Comment: @sridhars - Sorry it is not renaming I mean select it with a new alias like this `SELECT h.Area AS hare, t.Area AS TArea, ...` . This won't rename it, but select it with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your `UNION`. It consists of two parts:

```
SELECT *
FROM DCHDR AS H
LEFT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON H.DC_No = T.DC_Nos
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM DCHDR AS H
RIGHT JOIN DCDTL AS T ON H.DC_No = T.DC_Nos
WHERE H.DC_date
BETWEEN '2013-03-02'
AND '2013-03-11'
```

The condition in a `UNION` is applied to the latter part. And the second part is just an `INNER JOIN`, because you have a condition on a left part column. And since `UNION` removes duplicate rows the overal query is equal to your first `LEFT JOIN`.